# [[maybe_unused]] and Constructors

Tags: c++, c++17

Trying to compile the sqlpp17 codebase with gcc 8.2.1 and clang 6.0.1 have been a really strange experience. The code pushes the compilers to the limits and I hit probably a few compiler bugs in the meantime.

From the GCC Docs, [[maybe_unused]] is implemented since version 7, but if used this way:

```
struct foo {
    foo([[maybe_unused]] bool thing1)
    {
    }
};
```

I hit this specific error:

> ```
> <source>:2:9: error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token
>      foo([[maybe_unused]] bool thing1)
>          ^
> <source>:2:9: error: expected ')' before '[' token
>      foo([[maybe_unused]] bool thing1)
>         ~^
>          )
> Compiler returned: 1
> ```

Now, I know too little about C++17 to know if this error is correct, I know that clang 6 compiles that part fine (and fails somewhere else).

So, who's right, clang or gcc? (flags are  -std=gnu++17 for both clang and gcc, generated by CMake)

Comment: Simplest example I could make: https://godbolt.org/z/ctFnY5 . In short, gcc fails to compile constructors with attributes on the arguments

Comment: gcc  bug, pure and simple: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/V_n2Xs

Comment: @Justin, only for the first argument!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a known bug in g++: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81429 G++ doesn't parse correctly `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute for first argument of the constructor.

Comment: And the bug is still setting there @2019-Feb-7

Comment: This syntax works (with gcc-8): `foo(bool thing1 [[maybe_unused]])`

Comment: Unfortunately, also in gcc 9.1. [the bug is still present...](https://godbolt.org/z/doNlSx). @Algorys' solution works, however.

Comment: Fixed in GCC 9.3.