# Attribute [[maybe_unused]] in ctor doesn't work with std::make_unique?

Tags: attributes, g++, c++17, unique-ptr

I don't completely follow why below code doesn't compile, could you please help me understand that? Is this a compiler (GCC g++ 8.3.1) fault, or am I doing something wrong here?

```
struct S {
    S([[maybe_unused]] int &i) {}  
};

int main()
{
    int a = 4;
    auto p = std::make_unique<S>(a);
}
```

If I remove attribute [[maybe_unused]] from ctor, everything compiles.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52263141/maybe-unused-and-constructors

Comment: Thank you, didn't find that asnwer. Closing question.